# Binary to decimal project

Tags: java, math

What I am trying to do is a program that takes a binary number and passes it to a decimal base so I try to ask the user for a binary number (3 digits), so I request a digit number and keep each digit in the variable. Then I want to insert the integer binary number into its own variable How do I do this?

Thanks for the help :)

```
        case 1:
            System.out.println("The binary number must be 3 digits!");
            System.out.println("Enter digit 1: ");
            do{
                binarydigit1 = in.nextInt();
            } while (binarydigit1 > 1 || binarydigit1 < 0);
            System.out.println("Enter digit 2: ");
            do {
                binarydigit2 = in.nextInt();
            } while (binarydigit2 > 1 || binarydigit2 < 0);
            System.out.println("Enter digit 3: ");
            do {
                binarydigit3 = in.nextInt();
            } while (binarydigit3 > 1 || binarydigit3 < 0);
            break;
```

I don't get error I just don't know how to do this.

Comment: Why so complicated? Integer.parseInt("101", 2)

Comment: "Then I want to insert the integer binary number into its own variable" What do you mean? Combining the three digits into a single number and assigning it to a variable?

Comment: A wild guess: `int number = binaryDigit1 * 4 + binaryDigit2 * 2 + binaryDigit3`.

Comment: Then I want to insert the integer binary number into its own variable" What do you mean? Combining the three digits into a single number and assigning it to a variable? yes thats what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't push 3 different variables into one variable, but you can push them into an array

```
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList(); //b is the binary number list
        b.add(binarydigit1);
        b.add(binarydigit2);
        b.add(binarydigit3);
```

Or you can just do the conversation using throw a formula using your variables just as they are.